# SSH from EC2 to itself by different user which is not ec2-user

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm newbie in AWS and need some help.
I created user (ronen) in my EC2 instance (In addition to the ec2-user) by the adduser command.
Then I created public/private key by the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f my-cmd-gen-keys -t dsa
```

The following files created:

```
my-cmd-gen-keys
my-cmd-gen-keys.pub
```

I copied the content of the public file to **/home/ronen/.ssh/authorized_keys**.
Then I tried to execute the command and got permission denied:

```
**

> ssh -i ronen-key-pair ronen@ip-172-31-19-13 
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

**
```

(I must to confess that it worked for me few days ago before I terminated the instance, probably missing something)

below is the command with -v option

```
> [ronen@ip-172-31-19-13 ~]$ ssh -i ronen-key-pair ronen@ip-172-31-19-13 -v

> OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config > debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    > line 58: Applying options for * debug1: Connecting to ip-172-31-19-13
    > [172.31.19.13] port 22. debug1: Connection established. debug1:
    > identity file ronen-key-pair type 2 debug1: key_load_public: No such
    > file or directory debug1: identity file ronen-key-pair-cert type -1
    > debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local
    > version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4 debug1: Remote protocol version
    > 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4 debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000 debug1: Authenticating to
    > ip-172-31-19-13:22 as 'ronen' debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug1:
    > SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    > debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 debug1: kex:
    > server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit>
    > compression: none debug1: kex: client->server cipher:
    > chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    > debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64 debug1: kex:
    > curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64 debug1: expecting
    > SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    > SHA256:gQm7jn7pje2jeEY+LrwW2BIWuS/7qF+QfI6HQ9JZ5Jw debug1: Host
    > 'ip-172-31-19-13' is known and matches the ECDSA host key. debug1:
    > Found key in /home/ronen/.ssh/known_hosts:1 debug1: rekey after
    > 134217728 blocks debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting
    > SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug1: rekey after
    > 134217728 blocks debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received debug1:
    > kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
    > debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received debug1: Authentications that
    > can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic debug1: Next
    > authentication method: gssapi-keyex debug1: No valid Key exchange
    > context debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic debug1:
    > Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information No
    > Kerberos credentials available (default cache:
    > KEYRING:persistent:1001)
    > 
    > debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more
    > information No Kerberos credentials available (default cache:
    > KEYRING:persistent:1001)
    > 
    > debug1: Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Offering DSA
    > public key: ronen-key-pair debug1: Authentications that can continue:
    > publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic debug1: No more authentication
    > methods to try. Permission denied
    > (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Below is the directory/files permission of this user:

```
[ronen@ip-172-31-19-13 ~]$ ls -lrtaR
.:
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 ronen ronen  231 Jul 27  2018 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 ronen ronen  193 Jul 27  2018 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ronen ronen   18 Jul 27  2018 .bash_logout
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root    35 Jan 27 17:42 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ronen ronen  641 Jan 27 17:44 ronen-key-pair.pub
-rw------- 1 ronen ronen  672 Jan 27 17:44 ronen-key-pair
drwxrwxr-x 2 ronen ronen   48 Jan 27 17:49 .ssh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ronen ronen    0 Jan 27 18:56 client
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ronen ronen    0 Jan 27 18:56 server
drwx------ 3 ronen ronen  171 Jan 27 18:56 .
-rw------- 1 ronen ronen 3539 Jan 27 18:58 .bash_history

./.ssh:
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ronen ronen 641 Jan 27 17:45 authorized_keys
drwxrwxr-x 2 ronen ronen  48 Jan 27 17:49 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 ronen ronen 380 Jan 27 17:55 known_hosts
drwx------ 3 ronen ronen 171 Jan 27 18:56 ..
[ronen@ip-172-31-19-13 ~]$
```

Thank you for your help,
Ronen

Comment: `I must to confess that it worked for me few days ago before I terminated the instance, probably missing something` , what do you mean by this, is your instance still running.

Comment: try with restarting sshd service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta: this isn't a programming issue and probably belongs on superuser or unix.SX, or possibly security.SX. But last time I tried to migrate something it was more hassle than it was worth.

https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8#FILES (formatting simplified)

> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
>
> If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or replaced by unauthorized users. In this case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”.

You have both .ssh (drwxrwxr-x) and .ssh/authorized_keys (-rw-rw-r--) writable by group. On modern Linux systems userids are often put in their own groups so that 'group' access doesn't actually permit access by other users, but OpenSSH can't practically detect that (especially in a possible Kerberos, LDAP, or YP/NIS environment) and must assume that 'group' access does allow other users and is unsafe.

Also, recent versions of OpenSSH (since 7.0, including your 7.4) no longer support DSA keys by default. This can be fixed, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1016989/ssh-dsa-keys-no-longer-work-for-password-less-authentication
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247612/ssh-keeps-skipping-my-pubkey-and-asking-for-a-password
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys

but unless you have some positive reason to use DSA specifically, I suggest changing to either rsa-2048 (compatible with everything and secure enough) or ecdsa(-any) or ed25519 (now widespread though not universal, more efficient, and slightly higher safety margin).

Comment: Thank you dave_thompson_085. your answer help to solve the issue.One more comment, I had to change the home directory permissions to 700 as well.
e.g: chmod 700 /home/<username>

Comment: That's surprising -- the `ls` posted in your Q shows `.` as 700 already, which is why I omitted it. (Note the man page quote lists all three.)